# CXF JAX-RS downloading resource from URL

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I want to send across resource(say a image) from some URL to front-end.
The typical way of doing this is to create a File and build the response. Is there any way in which I don't have to create the File in java code and still send the resource to front-end.

**Front-end cannot access the URL due to some constraints.**
Currently the Pseudo code looks like this.

```
File file = new File(fullPath);
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(modulePDF);
```

I want to send content of URL to front-end without creating file. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

What way did have in mind to actually obtain the file without creating a `File` object?

Not sure I fully understand the complete requirement, but you don't *have* to create a `File` object. You can send out a `byte[]`, or simply write it to the response output stream by returning `StreamingOutput`.

```
@GET
public StreamingOutput getString() {
    return new StreamingOutput(){
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) 
                throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            // write to the `out` stream
        }
    };
}
```

For anything more than that, you will have to greatly elaborate on your requirement. The information you've provided, (especially the highlighted line) doesn't quite paint a clear enough problem as to what actual **problem** is you are facing.

Comment: I want to send the content of URL to front-end without creating any file in the process.

Comment: What is the "content of the URL"? That's what makes no sense. Where is the content coming from?

Comment: URL is something like http://abc:2030//resources/images/image.gif
i have to send this image to front-end

Comment: Is that file on your file system? If so are you asking how can user get the image without even going through the JAX-RS method? I'm not sure I understand the problem, and why creating a File causes a problem for you?

Comment: no this is some external URL, which my java code calls and sends the image(which comes as the response of calling this URL) to front-end.

Comment: You can use any client API and get an `InputStream` of the file. Then stream out the input stream to the output stream as shown above or simple create a byte[] array from the `InputStream`.